# How to reference column of UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

Given the query

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.email, t2.color FROM t1
UNION (SELECT * FROM t2)
```

Now in the first select I cannot reference t2, I get

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "t2"`
```

So I assumed I need to alias the union select, as in:

```
UNION (SELECT * FROM t2) AS t
```

but I get syntax errors for this as well. What's the correct way to address this?

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96d5cf/3

Table t1:

```
--username |    email
tom             tom@example.com
alex            alex@example.com
```

Table t2:

```
--color
black
blue
```

Expected result:

```
col1        col2...
value1      value2...
value11     value21...
```

Comment: Your query is invalid in both syntax and meaning. What is your intention in this query? Please provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach aded a SQL fiddle, but I almost assume what I want to do, doesn't make any sense. I want to select the color in the first query and in ordre to reference it, I thought it's possible to alias the query of the UNION

Comment: I've edited your question with your sample date. What is your expected output?

Comment: You want to have `username, email, color` columns and match each user with each color? Or is there some relation between colors and users that you didn't mention?

Comment: Where do `'value1'`, `'value2'`, etc. come from in the expected results.  They have nothing to do with the values you've described in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not doing wrong, in order to get color value you need to define the *relationship* via primary key `t1(username/userid)` and foreign key `t2(t1.username/t1.userid)` between table `t1` and `t2`. So, the query would be

```
select t1.username, t2.color 
from t1 
inner join t2 on t2.username/userid = t1.username/userid;
```